# Stop the execution of setInterval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

I'm building a little fantasy game. In the game, the player has a endurance limit. For each click at the map, the endurance bar is increased:

```
angular.element('.click').click(function() {
var endurance_click = angular.element('.progressbar').height();
angular.element('.progressbar').css('height', endurance_click-20);
});
```

The thing I want to accomplish is that if you click around at the map, and stops before you have run out of endurance, and wait for 2sec, I want to fire an function that restores you endurance. When you decide to move on, I want to stop the function.

I have tried `setInterval`, but the function just keeps running.

Here is my code:

```
//Call a function that should restore the endurance
d = window.setInterval(restoreEndurance2, 2000);

function restoreEndurance2()
{
    var endurance_restore = angular.element('.progressbar').height();
    angular.element('.progressbar').css('height', endurance_restore+20);
    if(endurance_restore >= 320) //If it's restored
    {
        alert(endurance_restore);
        clearInterval(d);
    }
}
```

How can I make the function stop when I start navigate through the map?

Comment: You already have `clearInterval(d);` which should do it. So what's the problem? `clearInterval` is how you stop an `setInterval`.

Comment: Just a tip, for the maintainability of your program it's probably better to separate the logic from your presentation.

Comment: @MattBurland: Well, the clearInterval in my code is fired when you have full endurance. But let's say that you have 50% endurance, and waits 2seconds, and then move on again. I want to stop the setInterval when I do that.

Comment: @user500468: Yeah, so use `clearInterval` when you move.

Comment: @MattEurland: Yeah, but where do I put clearInterval in the code to stop the setInterval When I do a click?

Comment: if d is a global variable. You can put clearInterval anywhere you want..

Comment: @plbsam: I have tried to put it everywhere inside the if-statement, but the function does not stop when I make a move.

Comment: I solved it. I just set clearInterval before my function call.